# An explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^+ \times {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ and ${\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})\times {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, spin-geometry, classical-groups, exceptional-isomorphisms

I am interested in the following isomorphism

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}^+\times {\rm Spin}^c(3,1)& \cong \mathbb{R}^+\times {\rm Spin}(3,1) \times {\rm U}(1) \tag{1}\\
&\cong \mathbb{C}^+\times {\rm Spin}(3,1)  \tag{2}
\\&\cong \mathbb{C}^+\times {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \tag{3}\\
&\cong {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{C}) \tag{4}\\
&\cong {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}) \times {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}) \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

I get 8 parameters on each side. There should therefore be an isomorphism between the two groups.

Comment: These groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added equations numbers. Can you state which line fails?

Comment: Line $1$ is false, line $3 \to 4$ is false, and line $4 \to 5$ is false.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How does ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ differ from ${\rm Spin}(3,1) \times {\rm U}(1)$? What is  ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$?

Comment: It's a quotient of that group: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spin%5Ec

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I visualize the Spin(3,1) as the exponential of a bivector of $Cl_{3,1}$. I visualize U(1) as the exponential of a pseudo-scalar of $Cl_{3,1}$. What is the $Cl_{3,1}$ representation of $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Clifford algebra side of things, but in terms of the isomorphism $Spin(3, 1) \cong SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ the relevant copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is given by $\{ \pm I \}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why is $\mathbb{C}^+\times {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C}) 
\cong {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{C})$ false?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Its because GL+(2,ℂ) doesnt exist right -  if the determinant is positive a non-imaginary, its just GL+(2,R)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real case we have:

$~$ (a) $\,\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}\cong\mathrm{Spin}(2,1)$

$~$ (b) $\,\mathrm{GL}_2^+\mathbb{R}\,=\,\mathbb{R}^+\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}\,\cong\,\mathbb{R}^+\!\times\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$

Here, by $HK$ I mean the elementwise product $\{hk\mid h\in H,k\in K\}$ when $H$ and $K$ are subsets of a group. In these examples, each of $H$, $K$, $HK$ will be groups, and elements from $H$ and $K$ will commute (one of the conditions for $HK$ to be a direct product), but $H\cap K$ is $\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ in many of the following examples (in which case $HK$ is not direct).

In the complex case we have:

$~$ (w) $\,\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}\,\cong\,\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$

$~$ (x) $\,\mathrm{GL}_2^+\mathbb{C}\,=\,\mathbb{R}^+\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}\,\cong\,\mathbb{R}^+\!\times\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}$

$~$ (y) $\,\mathrm{Spin}^{\mathbb{C}}(3,1) \,\cong\, S^1\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C} \,\cong\, S^1\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C} \,\cong\, \mathrm{U}(1)\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$

$~$ (z) $\,\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}^\times\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{C}^\times\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}$.

You should think of the middle two, $\mathrm{GL}^+\mathbb{C}$ and $S^1\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}$, as being enhancements of $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $S^1$ respectively, and the last being the "full" enhancement by $\mathbb{C}^\times=\mathbb{R}^+S^1\cong\mathbb{R}^+\times S^1$.

Note $H\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}K$ means the quotient $(H\times K)/\mathbb{Z}_2$. The context is that $H$ and $K$ have distinguished (central) copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (i.e. $\{\pm1\}$ or $\{\pm I_2\}$), which gives us a "diagonal" copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in $H\times K$ we can quotient by.

In theory it's possible for $H\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}K$ and $H\times K$ to be isomorphic via a really weird and non-obvious isomorphism. I don't think that's the case in (y) or (z) above, but I don't see a clean argument as to why at the moment.

Those in (w) have real dimension 6, those in (x) and (y) have real dimension 7 (but are those in (x) are not isomorphic to those in (y), or vice-versa), and those in (z) have real dimension 8.

There is no $\mathbb{C}^+$, and $\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{R}\times\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{R}$ is not isomorphic to anything previously mentioned. I suspect your (4) was supposed to be $\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{C}$, which on the lie algebra level has $\mathfrak{gl}_2\mathbb{C}=\mathfrak{gl}_2\mathbb{R}\oplus i\mathfrak{gl}_2\mathbb{R}$ as *vector spaces* but **not** as lie algebras, so $\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{C}\cong\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{R}\times\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{R}$ is very badly false.

Comment: Wow that is a great answer. Thanks. What if we extend the analysis to quotient bundles and homogenous spaces? Does $(\mathbb{R}^+\times {\rm Spin}(3,1) \times {\rm U}(1) )/ {\rm GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$ leads to anything sensible?

Comment: You could speak of $(\Bbb R^+\times{\rm Spin}(3,1)\times{\rm U}(1))/(\Bbb R^+\times{\rm Spin}(2,1))$, which I think is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times\Bbb R\times S^1$. (That ${\rm U}(1)=S^1$ factor doesn't really affect anything.) If we quotient the numerator by $\Bbb Z_2$, we could instead speak of ${\rm GL}_2\Bbb C/{\rm GL}_2^+\Bbb R$ which I think would be diffeomorphic to $(S^2\times_{\Bbb Z_2}S^1)\times\Bbb R$.

Comment: Isn't S^2 x R a cylinder?

Comment: $\Bbb R\times S^1$ is an infinite cylinder (as a 2D surface). $S^2\times\Bbb R$ is a 3D volume, but is not a solid infinite cylinder (that would instead be $D^2\times\Bbb R$, where $D^2$ is a solid disk, either open or closed depending on whether you want the solid cylinder to include its boundary or not).

Comment: Is it the case that ℝ$^+$×Spin(3,1)×U(1)/ℤ2 $\cong$ GL$_2$ℂ?

Comment: Yes, that is true. We have $\Bbb C^\times=\Bbb R^+S^1\cong\Bbb R^+\times{\rm U}(1)$, so that is basically (z) in my answer, which you could also rewrite as $\Bbb R^+\times{\rm Spin}^{\Bbb C}(3,1)$.